# Work with Greek Script in Objective-C / Cocoa / SQL

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, unicode, character-encoding

I am planning to write a software which I want to save, load, display etc. Greek script. I am going to use Objective-C, Cocoa and will want to store Greek words / letters etc. in a SQL database.

Can I just change my keyboard layout to 'Greek' and work with Greek Script? Is it as simple as this? - or will I somehow have to find a way around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to do anything special. The Greek alphabet is just a subset of standard Unicode.

Just make sure your database is created with UTF-8 or other appropriate encoding. Then there won't be anything else to do in your code. You'll be able to support anything the user can enter.

Comment: thanks a lot. I was just wondering, because some data I found is using ASCII to represent Greek in XML documents, and I was wondering why that is. What reason is there for people to use ASCII over Unicode?

Comment: Of course, it depends on what you really want.  If you want the user to be able to enter text written in the various dialects of Ancient Greek, for example, with all the weird diacritical marks and so forth, then you may need a special font installed to do that, and a special input method; the standard Greek support isn't going to cover that.  It's all in Unicode, yes; but without a way to type it, and without a font capable of displaying it, that doesn't get you very far.

Comment: @KenGoldhaus You can't use ASCII to show Greek characters. You need to use Unicode or other encoding that supports the Greek characters. ASCII only has basic letters A-Z, numbers 0-9, and some punctuation.

Comment: ASCII is used for Greek when using a font like Symbol, where "s" gives you a sigma, etc.  So as far as Unicode is concerned, you're typing in Roman characters, but the font happens to use glyphs that look like Greek letters.  Or that's my understanding.  That's very limited, and won't give you a very satisfying user experience; I think it's mostly useful for typing mathematical formulas that use Greek letters, for example, rather than for representing real Greek text.

Comment: @bhaller Then technically that isn't using ASCII for Greek. That's a hack dependent on a special font.

Comment: @rmaddy, you certainly can.  That's what the Symbol font is for.

Comment: Sure, it's a hack.  But it represents the characters with ASCII, and what the user sees are Greek characters.  That's what @KenGoldhaus was asking about.  It's not correct to say that it is not possible.

Comment: @bhaller That hack will only work when viewing the data in that specific app. If I look at that ASCII file/data in some other tool/app, I'll see ASCII (non-Greek) characters that make little sense. It's not a good idea to suggest such a solution. It should be done properly.

Comment: I do understand that ASCII does not include Greek script, but I was wondering why it is used to 'stand for' ancient Greek sometimes, (Beta-Code) - if one could just use unicode? As far as I'm concerned, unicode does have all the diacritical marks necessary to type ancient greek -or at least I am doing so on OS El Capitan (maybe other OS are not so easy with this?)?

Comment: As long as the fact that the text is in Symbol is preserved, there is no issue.  It's a perfectly good solution for some situations.  The Symbol font, provided by Apple, is expressly intended for this use.  If you'd like to argue with Apple, feel free; but the train has rather left the station on this one, I'm afraid.

Comment: Why do people use ASCII instead of Unicode?  Because it's more compact in its memory usage, because it is a simpler standard, because it is portable to systems that don't have good Unicode support, for historical reasons (a lot of legacy code works only with ASCII, not with Unicode), because they don't have a good font supporting the necessary Unicode characters, ...

Comment: I don't follow. Why would I want to argue with Apple? Everything is running smoothly, I *am* typing 'ancient-greek' without any problems. Maybe this is the reason why I don't see the point of Beta-Code and other ASCII hacks that are used to represent other scripts, precisely because I have never had problems with 'installing fonts' etc. on my machine?

Comment: I was suggesting that @rmaddy could argue with Apple if he wants to be doctrinaire about never using ASCII to represent Greek characters, since the Symbol font is an Apple-supplied font.  That comment was not directed at you.

Comment: Anyway, the question has been answered, and this discussion is inappropriately long.  Let's call it quits or move to chat.

Comment: Yes. Thanks a lot.